# Neural Network model not improving accuracy. Scaling problem or model problem?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, scaling

I am trying to create a simple neural network to see how it works.

A second degree ecuation has the form (x-x1)*(x-x2)=0, and if you rearrange it, it will become ax^2+bx+c=0, where a=1, b=-2*x1*x2, c=x1*x2. I want to create a neural network where the inputs are (a,b), and the outputs are (x1,x2).

In order to do this, I have created 2 functions that create the data, and stored them in matrices named input and output.

I have created a neural network with layers 2x2x2 (including inputs and output), and tested it out with bad results, even after tweaking it.

I guess the issue that I have is regarding the data, because the neural network works and spits out a result, but its not good.

I don't know where the issue is, but my guess is that it has to do with the data scaling. I have tried to introduce the data without scaling it, but I get the same bad results.

The idea is that I provide enough training, so the weights and biases are such that provided any input data, the outcome will be very close to the desired output.

This is the code of the whole program

```
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from sklearn.metrics import  confusion_matrix
import itertools

import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'

from random import randint
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler


import numpy as np

def abc(x1, x2):
    b=-2*x1*x2
    c=x1*x2
    sol=[b,c]
    return sol

a=10
b=10
c=a*b


def Nx2(N, M):
    matrix=[]
    n = N+ 1
    m= M + 1
    for i in range(1,n):
        for j in range(1,m):
            temp=[i,j]
            matrix.append(temp)
    final_matrix = np.array(matrix)
    return final_matrix

output=Nx2(a, b)

# print(output)

input=[]
for i in range(0,c):
    temp2=abc(output[i,0],output[i,1])
    input.append(temp2)
input=np.array(input)

print(input)

train_labels = output
train_samples = input

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_train_samples = scaler.fit_transform((train_samples).reshape(-1,1))
scaled_train_samples=scaled_train_samples.reshape(-1,2)

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_train_labels = scaler.fit_transform((train_labels).reshape(-1,1))
scaled_train_labels=scaled_train_labels.reshape(-1,2)

print(scaled_train_samples)
print(scaled_train_labels)

model = Sequential([
    Dense(2, input_shape=(2,), activation='sigmoid'),
    Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'),
])

print(model.weights)

model.compile(SGD(lr=0.01), loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(scaled_train_labels, scaled_train_labels, validation_split=0.2, batch_size=10, epochs=20, shuffle=True, verbose=2)

print(model.summary())
print(model.weights)
```

These are the kind of results that I am getting.

```
 Epoch 1/20 
     - 0s - loss: 0.1456 - accuracy: 0.5500 - val_loss: 0.3715 - val_accuracy: 0.0500 Epoch 2/20
     - 0s - loss: 0.1449 - accuracy: 0.5500 - val_loss: 0.3704 - val_accuracy: 0.0500 Epoch 3/20
     - 0s - loss: 0.1443 - accuracy: 0.5500 - val_loss: 0.3692 - val_accuracy: 0.0500 Epoch 4/20
     - 0s - loss: 0.1437 - accuracy: 0.5500 - val_loss: 0.3681 - val_accuracy: 0.0500 Epoch 5/20
     - 0s - loss: 0.1431 - accuracy: 0.5500 - val_loss: 0.3670 - val_accuracy: 0.0500 Epoch 6/20
     - 0s - loss: 0.1425 - accuracy: 0.5500 - val_loss: 0.3658 - val_accuracy: 0.0500 Epoch 7/20
     - 0s - loss: 0.1419 - accuracy: 0.5500 - val_loss: 0.3647 - val_accuracy: 0.0500 Epoch 8/20
     - 0s - loss: 0.1413 - accuracy: 0.5500 - val_loss: 0.3636 - val_accuracy: 0.0500 Epoch 9/20
     - 0s - loss: 0.1407 - accuracy: 0.5500 - val_loss: 0.3625 - val_accuracy: 0.0500 Epoch 10/20
     - 0s - loss: 0.1401 - accuracy: 0.5500 - val_loss: 0.3613 - val_accuracy: 0.0500 Epoch 11/20
     - 0s - loss: 0.1395 - accuracy: 0.5500 - val_loss: 0.3602 - val_accuracy: 0.0500 Epoch 12/20
     - 0s - loss: 0.1389 - accuracy: 0.5500 - val_loss: 0.3591 - val_accuracy: 0.0500 Epoch 13/20
     - 0s - loss: 0.1383 - accuracy: 0.5500 - val_loss: 0.3580 - val_accuracy: 0.0500 Epoch 14/20
     - 0s - loss: 0.1377 - accuracy: 0.5500 - val_loss: 0.3568 - val_accuracy: 0.0500 Epoch 15/20
     - 0s - loss: 0.1372 - accuracy: 0.5500 - val_loss: 0.3557 - val_accuracy: 0.0500 Epoch 16/20
     - 0s - loss: 0.1366 - accuracy: 0.5500 - val_loss: 0.3546 - val_accuracy: 0.0500 Epoch 17/20
     - 0s - loss: 0.1360 - accuracy: 0.5500 - val_loss: 0.3535 - val_accuracy: 0.0500 Epoch 18/20
     - 0s - loss: 0.1354 - accuracy: 0.5500 - val_loss: 0.3524 - val_accuracy: 0.0500 Epoch 19/20
     - 0s - loss: 0.1348 - accuracy: 0.5500 - val_loss: 0.3513 - val_accuracy: 0.0500 Epoch 20/20
     - 0s - loss: 0.1342 - accuracy: 0.5500 - val_loss: 0.3502 - val_accuracy: 0.0500
```

Can someone point me into the right direction?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

1. You are using accuracy for a *regression* problem, which is meaningless (accuracy is only applicable to *classification* problems). You should monitor the performance of your model only with the loss, here MSE (for the same reason, you don't need to import `confusion_matrix` or `categorical_crossentropy`).
2. You erroneously use `sigmoid` activation for your last layer; in regression problems, this should be `linear` (or leave blank, as `linear` is the default Keras activation).
3. You should use the `relu` activation for your intermediate layers, not `sigmoid`.
4. Your model looks way too simple, and it is unclear why you feel constrained to just use 2-node layers (you should *not*, except of course for the output one).

All in all, here is a starting point:

```
model = Sequential([
    Dense(30, input_shape=(2,), activation='relu'),
    # Dense(10, activation='relu'), # uncomment for experimentation
    Dense(2, activation='linear'),
])

model.compile(SGD(lr=0.01), loss='mean_squared_error')
```

but the code word here is *experimentation*...

Last but not least, you seem to have a typo in your `model.fit()` (you pass two times the labels, instead of the samples) - be sure to fix this, too.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have implemented the changes you suggested, and the loss has decreased. The reason why I feel constrained to just use 2 node layers and only 2 layers is to do the operations by hand after I got some good results. By hand I mean with an excel sheet or something like that, where all the numbers are visible, and I can understand in a cuantitative way what is happening. Thank you

Comment: @ArmanMojaver I see, but we can usually have this kind of manual reproducibility, or performance - seldom both (although it might be possible with toy datasets, like here).

Comment: @ArmanMojaver BTW, and since the answer has resolved your issue, do you mind accepting it? Thanks...

Comment: Your answer has provided some improvement, but the issue is not resolved yet. I just haven't had the time to upload the results that I got. I am going to leave the question open for now, just in case someone else wants to participate. Thank you.

Comment: Arguably, adoption of what I have proposed should have led to a completely new situation, with the existing one (as described in the question) being now obsolete. Updating questions in a fundamental way, after answers, is not how SO works; instead, you are always welcome to open a new question with the new situation and any new issues you may be facing. It's not clear what is the issue not resolved yet and, after all, your exact question was "*Can someone point me into the right direction?*, which has arguably been delivered.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately your suggestion has not led to a completely new situation, because I have similar results. I still believe that the issue is related to the data scaling, without knowing what it is exactly. I appreciate you explaining me how SO works, but I would like to wait a little bit to see if someone else is kind enough to provide me some other input. Thank you :)

Comment: Suit yourself. Even keeping your own model structure (2xDense(2)), in 50 epochs the validation loss goes down to 0.16 with the train loss to 0.07 (that's if one takes the trouble to rerun your code, of course). Contrary to the accuracy, there is absolutely no way for anyone to claim that these results are "good" or "bad", but do not sound similar to the ones posted. Good luck anyway...